# Shark was unable to find symbol information for this address range - iPhone

Tags: iphone, build, debugging, symbols, shark

I'm trying to use Shark to determine which method(s) are taking the most time in my iPhone app. After sampling, I get this:
[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7871/screenshot20091117at503.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7871/screenshot20091117at503.png)

Clicking the "!" button yields:

> Shark was unable to find symbol
>   information for this address range.
>   Typically this happens because the
>   application was compiled without
>   symbols or they have been subsequently
>   stripped away. In Xcode, make sure the
>   "Generate Debug Symbols" checkbox is
>   selected (passes the -g flag to the
>   compiler). Note that this does not
>   affect code optimization, and does not
>   typically alter performance
>   significantly. However, the extra
>   symbol information does consume
>   significantly more space and may bloat
>   the size of the executable.

But I AM using the Debug option, and I am running on my Device. And Generate Debug Symbols IS checked. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this applies to Shark on device, but I know that when running Instruments with the iPhone Simulator, one has to select the most recent SDK. If you run with a previous SDK, you see no debug info.